# Recovery of data after remounting of a partition

Tags: shell-script

I had to remount one of the hard disc partition as it was not mounting because of some unknown reason. After remounting all my data are gone from that partition and the directory also got changed. Can anyone help me to recover my data from the partition?

Comment: You might have better answers at https://serverfault.com/